# How can I make my existing VIP theme to multisite

Tags: multisite

I have a VIP theme setup at my local which I now need to make a multisite.

The folder structure I have at my local is:
`var>www>html>yrc>wp>wp-content>themes>vip>yrc-theme` (yrc-theme is my custom theme).

In order to change the installation to multisite mode I need to add the line in wp-config.php file:

```
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);
just before this one:
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

The only `wp-config.php` file I can find is under **var/www/html/yrc** folder but I don't see the following line in it:

```
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */
```

Which file should I put `define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);` in?

**EDIT:**
Inside `var>www>html>yrc>wp` folder I can see a file named `wp-config-sample.php` where I have `/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */`. Shall I copy this file to create a `wp-config.php` and use that? I never used VIP before so got absolutely no clue.

Answer (score 0):

You should first run the installer for WordPress which will generate a `wp-config.php` in your `var>www>html>yrc>wp`.

You can do it manually as well by copying the `wp-config-sample.php` to `wp-config.php`, do it only if you have understanding of what this file should contain.

To run the installer in your local host simply use the URL `http://localhost/yrs/wp`, this should initiate the installer.

Once this is done you can find a `wp-config.php` file in `var>www>html>yrc>wp` where you should add `define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);`

https://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress

https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network